# are there differences in energy consumption for displaying color?

Tags: display

The question stems from wanting to design UI's for mobile devices that consume the least power.

I'm assuming a dimmer screen will consume less power..but would, for example, ***green*** use less power than ***red***?

Or maybe it'd be best to stick to grayscale?

Comment: It all depends on the display technology used.

Comment: Run some experiments and find out. From general knowledge I can tell, that human eye is much more sensitive to green than to red, so for same visible intensity, green will be actually less intense energetically.

Comment: If you really want the *least* power consumption, just communicate with the user through a series of blinks of the status LED.

Comment: @Samuel It reminds me of R2D2 for some reason..

Comment: @EugeneSh. Exactly, no one will be able to understand it, but everyone will love it.

Comment: For LED displays I can image that the red color would need least power, because the voltage drop on red leds is smaller than that of the green or blue ones (for equal current). However, as stated by @Samuel, green/blue colors are experienced brighter, so you could lower the intensity of the color and get a lower power too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the display technology is a backlit LCD display, the color makes no difference.

If the display technology is an LED, it's possible to compare efficiencies. The mcd rating is already weighted by the human eye's luminosity function so you should be able to compare the numbers directly. Of course it only makes sense when you compare LEDs with equal viewing angle. The numbers would appear to indicate that (at least for Avago's line) red is the brightest at 20mA regardless of Vf, which makes it the clear winner since Vf is lower for red than for any other visible color.

Comment: Plus you have to consider colour combinations, for such things as OLED displays - Any secondary colour will use the combined power of the primary colours used to create the colour.

Comment: @Majenko Arguably I guess you could reduce the brightness of the component R/G/B to equal the same visually weighted brightness as a single color.

Comment: I'm assuming that since I'm talking about computers, tablets and phones, I'm only interested in LCD displays?